# how to display the features and intiatives belongs to particular quarter(period)-Rally

Tags: rally

I want to display the features and initiatives belongs to particular Quarter(period).

I tried with using Release combo box and filters. but release it not mapped either with feature nor initiative . please help to get features and initiatives and respective details belongs to a particular time period.

Answer (score 0):

Features have Release attribute, and can be filtered by Release:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'release',
    comboboxConfig: {
        fieldLabel: 'Select a Release:',
        labelWidth: 100,
        width: 300
    },

    addContent: function() {
        this._makeStore();
    },

    _makeStore: function(){
         Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
            fetch: ['FormattedID','Name'],
            pageSize: 100,
            autoLoad: true,
            filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()],
            listeners: {
                load: this._onDataLoaded,
                scope: this
            }
        }); 
    },

   onScopeChange: function() {
        this._makeStore();
    },
```

You may see the source code of this example in the github repo [here](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/features-by-release-with-stories).

Initiatives do not have Release attribute but can be filtered by dates, e.g. PlannedEndDate
PlannedStartDate, ActualEndDate, ActualStartDate.